# iOS simulator and XCode to simulate Compass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-location

I am aware there is now a way to simulate location, but is there a way to simulate compass values?.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compass is not in the list of the hardware interactions supported by the simulator and CLLocationManager headingAvailable reports it's not available on the simulator.

Also, in this doc:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

> Some location services require the presence of specific hardware on
>   the given device. For example, heading information is available only
>   for devices that contain a hardware compass. This class defines
>   several methods that you can use to determine which services are
>   currently available.

Specifically CLLocationManager has this class property to check if the compass is available:

```
+ (BOOL)headingAvailable
```

If I run this under the simulator:

```
NSLog(@"headingAvailable: %d", (int)[CLLocationManager headingAvailable]);
```

Outputs:

```
2011-11-08 22:38:26.873 Craplet[39975:b603] headingAvailable: 0
```